# iOS Significant Location Change Update (Location Update Frequency)

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

In my app I need to be able to have the app opened from a terminated state when the user has a significant change in location, so I'm calling the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method of CLLocationManager which does exactly that.

The app is opening as it should, but the problem is that I'm getting location change updates after long periods of time, for example 20 mins even though I've moved 1000's of meters and some times I don't get any update at all.  I need this to be updated after 500 meters.  It doesn't matter to me if it waits for a long period of time, but I need it to update after the 500 meters which is considered a Significant Location Change according to Apple's Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges).

```
- (void) checkIfSignificantLocationChange : (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {

    // Application is launched because of a significant location change
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey])
    {
        bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

        if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        {
            //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to see what I'm doing wrong here?  Why am I sometimes not getting any update at all after 30+ minutes even though I've moved well over 500 meters.

This method is called when the app detects a significant location change.  I'm using the iOS Simulator Location - Freeway Drive for testing purposes because I was sick of driving all over the place.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: any solution on this problem?

Comment: It could be a battery usage issue?